# How Do I Perform Gradient Descent for Discrete Predictions

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I have a dataframe, df, that is of the format:

Dimension, 1, 2, ..., 55

Dim1, 0.22, 0.152, ..., 0.10

...

Dim20, 0.52, 0.89, ..., 0.09

And I have a training set:

participant_1 :{Dimension: Dim12, response: {1,5,24,6,12}}
participant_2 :{Dimension: Dim5, response: {1,5,24,30,32}}

I would like to find weights w_1, w_2, ..., w_55 such that I can weight the columns of df corresponding to a participants response est, add the columns together and the row with the highest resulting value should be the participants dimension value.

What is the best method to find the set of weights in Python?

I am also looking for advice on how to format questions here.

Thank you!!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting